# How to update Records according to multiple Condition in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Recieving the following kind of data from the frontend

```
{
  activeTrue:['china','india'],
  activeFalse:['russia'],
  removeUser:['UK']
}
```

Record in my collection have the following schema

```
{
  user: "John",
  country: "UK",
  active: true
}
```

so if the country name exists in activeTrue then the active will be true and if it's included in activeFalse the active will be false for that document and if it falls in removeUser then we have to set the user field from document to "" the so, how to achieve this in one mongo updateMany operation such that we have to update on the basis of multiple conditions and accordingly if one is met we have to perform the operation on record based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to do three actions for the single request from the frontend.

To Update active as true:

```
db.test.updateMany({country: ["china","india"]}, {$set: {active: true}});
```

To Update active as false:

```
db.test.updateMany({country: "russia"}, {$set: {active: false}});
```

To remove:

```
db.test.remove({country: "UK"});
```

Comment: I'd achieved a similar kind of operation but can't, I do it with SIngle upateMany because in multiple if one of it fails like second or third it's difficult to rollback.

Comment: I guess MongoDB doesn't have any support for this behavior. Refer to the documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: Do you really need to roll back?  MongoDB supports transactions but it's not clear you need them here as opposed to appropriate error/retry logic. What I actually came here to say though is that you can bundle up these writes in a single bulk write operation to avoid traversing the network multiple times

Comment: Thanks, bulk is great alternative for this